# Add class to UL when LI is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="m_nav_tier m_nav_tier1">
    <li data-nav-tier="1">a</li>
    <li data-nav-tier="1">a</li>
    <li data-nav-tier="1">a</li>
    <li data-nav-tier="1">a</li>
    <li data-nav-tier="1">a</li>
</ul>
```

Using javascript how can I implement code to add a class to UL when user clicks on any LI?

This needs to be done in only Javascript, no jQuery.

Comment: See: [.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

Comment: Your question doesn't show any research effort. Maybe you tried, but finding a solution to your exact question is probably hard, since it's quite specific. But you have three quite generic problems to solve. 1. Capture the click of an element, 2. Find the parent of an element, 3. Add a class to an element. The solution to each should be easy to find, and after that combining them is trivial.

Comment: Event bubbles up from the `li`, you can set an click event handler on the `ul` to capture it.

Comment: Folks, you might notice that K2R is new to SO, so rather than down-voting the question, maybe encourage them with constructive criticism kinda like @GolezTrol did.

Comment: To be honest, I downvoted as well. I think a downvote and constructive criticism can be combined quite well. :)

Comment: appreciate it @jusop!  I am still getting used to SO and the down votes sting a bit, but i'm learning what not to do for next time :)

Answer (score 1):

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mx6c2um7/1/

```
var ul = document.body.getElementsByClassName('m_nav_tier')[0];
ul.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName == 'LI') {
        ul.classList.add('yourClassName');
    }
});
```

Each line explained:

```
var ul = document.body.getElementsByClassName('m_nav_tier')[0];
```

^ fetch the UL element from the DOM (must run after list is inserted into webpage)

```
ul.addEventListener('click',function(e) { ... });
```

^ listen for click events on the entire UL element (also listens for clicks on children elements which we will take advantage of)

```
if(e.target.tagName == 'LI') { .. }
```

^ check to see if the element we pressed was an LI element inside our UL

```
ul.classList.add('yourClassName');
```

^ use the classList property of DOMelements to add your new class

Comment: Just a note that the `classList` property and `getElementsByClassName` aren't available on older browsers, e.g. IE 8

Comment: The main problem I am having is finding the class.  I tried `document.body.getElementsByClassName('m_nav_tier')[0];`

Comment: Are you sure that you're invoking `getElementsByClassName` *after* you've inserted your UL into the webpage? If you code is running before it is inserted, then you wont get a match.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is.  Since this is for mobile, the nav is set to `display: none` until the user clicks the menu icon.

Comment: I tried changing to `height: 0` instead, but still seeing same results

Comment: if its height is set to 0 how do you expect users to click it?

Comment: @K2R The fiddle works, try putting the code at the bottom of your page

Answer (score 0):

I would use `document.querySelector/querySelectorAll` for getting your elements.  A little more verbose but also more indicative of your intent.

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul.m_nav_tier1 li')

for (var li, i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
{
     li = lis[i]
     li.addEventListener('click', function(evt){

         var ul = evt.target.parentElement
         //console.log(ul)

         ul.className += ' my-selected-class'
     })
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awa6vpep/

Comment: there may be a better way to add/remove the class on the `ul`, I just didn't really bother to look it up as I currently use jquery-lite to do that.

Comment: [classList.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)